# how to check is input is number or alphabet in sed

Tags: sed, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I check whether the user input is numerical or contains alphabetical characters. I use the code below to check it, but it is not working properly: it gives me either integer or not integer always. Please help me.

```
    echo "Enter version code" 
    read VERSIONCODE
    test -z $(echo "VERSIONCODE" | sed s/[[:digit:]]//g) && echo "integer" || echo "no integer"
    echo "$VERSIONCODE"
    sudo  sed "s/\(versionCode[[:space:]]*\)[0-9]*/\1${VERSIONCODE}/" Version.gradle
```

This is my output

```
Enter version code
1

no integer
```

I am getting unexpected for this

```
echo "Enter version code" 
read versionCode

if ! [[ "$versionCode" =~ ^[:digit:]+$ ]]
  then
    echo "Sorry integers only"
fi
echo "$versionCode"
sudo  sed "s/\(versionCode[[:space:]]*\)[0-9]*/\1${versionCode}/" Version.gradle
```

Comment: You don't need `sed` for it, you can use bash regex check in if condition and do the action accordingly in it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I am gretting unexcepted if. Please let me know how to use if in sed

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[:digit:]` by `[0-9]` in your regex:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter version code" 
read versionCode

if ! [[ "$versionCode" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  echo "Sorry integers only"
fi
echo "$versionCode"
```

This works for the `if` test. Adapt the last line of your code if necessary in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
<<<"$versionCode" sed -n '/^[[:digit:]]\+$/!q1' && echo OK || echo NOK
```

If the $versionCode is not numberic, set an exit code of 1.

Or perhaps you want a default:

```
<<<"$versionCode" sed '/^[[:digit:]]\+$/!s/.*/Default version/'
```

Comment: @Manoj could you be more explicit?

Answer (score 0):

You can always test for just chains of `[0-9]` to test for an integer:

```
$ echo 17 | sed -n '/^[0-9][0-9]*$/p'
17
$ echo 17.12 | sed -n '/^[0-9][0-9]*$/p'
$
```

but in general when testing for numbers in other contexts don't try to use a regexp (and so don't try to use sed, grep, etc.), use awk instead:

```
$ echo 17 | awk '{print $0, "is " ($0==($0+0) ? "" : "NOT ") "a number"}'
17 is a number

$ echo 17.12 | awk '{print $0, "is " ($0==($0+0) ? "" : "NOT ") "a number"}'
17.12 is a number

$ echo 17.12.53 | awk '{print $0, "is " ($0==($0+0) ? "" : "NOT ") "a number"}'
17.12.53 is NOT a number

$ echo 003 | awk '{print $0, "is " ($0==($0+0) ? "" : "NOT ") "a number"}'
003 is a number

$ echo 2e7 | awk '{print $0, "is " ($0==($0+0) ? "" : "NOT ") "a number"}'
2e7 is a number

$ echo 2f7 | awk '{print $0, "is " ($0==($0+0) ? "" : "NOT ") "a number"}'
2f7 is NOT a number
```